# Using a trigger BEFORE UPDATE to INSERT a row into my second table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this as table structure for my `pension_accounts` table and below the structure for my second table `pension_statement` table to select from table `pension_accounts` AFTER UPDATE trigger

```
Table structure for table `pension_accounts` 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pension_accounts` (
  `User_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Other_names` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `MaritalStatus` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Nationality` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Mobile` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `AccountType` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_NUMBER` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CountryCode` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Surname` (`Surname`,`Firstname`,`PASSWORD`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_update_pension_accounts`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_pension_accounts` BEFORE UPDATE ON `pension_accounts`
 FOR EACH ROW SET new.Modified_DateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
//
DELIMITER ;
```

AND SECOND TABLE `

### Table structure for table `pension_statement`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statement` (
  `StatementID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Statement_Surname` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Statement_Firstname` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Statement_ACCOUNT_NUMBER` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Statement_Balance` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Statement_Modified_DateTime` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Statement_Description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Statement_CurrencyType` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StatementID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

PROBLEM:
I tried adding an INSERT statement to that trigger to insert a row into `pension_statement` but it failed;

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `statement_history`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `statement_history` AFTER UPDATE ON `pension_accounts`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `pension_statement` (`StatementID`, `Statement_Surname`, `Statement_Firstname`, `Statement_ACCOUNT_NUMBER`, `Statement_Balance`, `Statement_Modified_DateTime`) VALUES (NULL, 'new.Statement_Surname', 'new.Statement_Firstname', 'new.Statement_ACCOUNT_NUMBER', 'new.Statement_Balance', 'new.Statement_Modified_DateTime')
//
DELIMITER ;
```

IT RETURNS THIS AS VALUES:

```
'new.Statement_Surname', 'new.Statement_Firstname', 'new.Statement_ACCOUNT_NUMBER', 'new.Statement_Balance', 'new.Statement_Modified_DateTime'
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: You can add statements to your existing trigger.  Does the current trigger work, for setting the TIMESTAMP?  You can add an INSERT statement to that trigger to insert a row into your second table.

Comment: @dubstylee Yes the trigger work fines, I just need to know how I can add an INSERT statement to that trigger to insert a row into your second table.

Comment: you can create compound statements by enclosing then in `begin` ... `end` blocks

Comment: @pala_   It didn't select what was inserted into the row so as to re-insert into the table pension_statement

Comment: yes. don't wrap your `new.*` values in quotes. they are variables, not strings. just use `values(null, new.Statement_Surname, ...)`

Comment: @pala_ yes. I have removed the quotes, but I get error so I changed new.Statement_Surname, ...)  to Statement_Surname, ...) It still returns empty rows

Comment: you're going to have to be specific about your error - also if you could please comment on my answer, so i can update that accordingly

Comment: @pala_ after removing the quotes as you instructed, it returns column field_name as values, this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute more than one statement in a trigger, by enclosing it in a `begin` ... `end` block. eg.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_update_pension_accounts`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_pension_accounts` BEFORE UPDATE ON `pension_accounts`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
   SET new.Modified_DateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   ... another statement here ... ;
   ... and another one ... ;
 END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

So simply add your `insert` statement after the `set` statement, and make sure it is inside the `begin` and `end`.

Okay, now that we have some more information, it is clear that what you want is an `after insert` trigger. It should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_pension_accounts` after insert ON `pension_accounts`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   insert into `statement` (statement_surname, statement_firstname, statement_account_number, statement_balance, statement_modified_datetime, statement_description, statement_currencytype) values(new.surname, new.firstname, new.account_number, 0, now(), 'something', 'something');
END//
```

You can only use the `new` prefix to refer to fields from the `pension_accounts` table in this instance, which means `statement_balance`, `statement_description`, `statement_currencytype` must get set to some default value. `statement_modified_datetime` can be set to the current time.

[here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6430b/1) showing this process working.

I am assuming, since there was no description of what you're trying to accomplish, is that you want to setup a statement, after a new account is opened? If this isn't the case, please go back to the question and describe what is you are trying to accomplish, rather than just showing us what you are trying.

Comment: Some one please help my issues

Comment: after removing the quotes as you instructed, it returns column field_name as values, this is the error

Comment: What is it that you want to be inserted into the statement table in the trigger?

Comment: the same value that the trigger updated, I want to select the new values as update and insert into the new table

Comment: your `pension_statement` table has none of the fields you are trying to insert.  it will never work. have you left fields out of the table definition? you show a compound key that references the `surname` field, but your table definition for `pension_statement` doesn't contain a `surname` field.

Comment: I left a few fields out and I have a Surname in pension_statement table

Comment: then please post your full table definition.

Comment: it still has none of the fields you are trying to insert. from your trigger - `INSERT INTO pension_statement (StatementID,`. why would this ever work? your `pension_statement` table has no `statementid` field. please post the entire table creation statement, not just some cherry picked fields.

Comment: I have update the pension_statement table query above

Comment: okay, so now there is no `new.modified_datetime` as there is no `modified_datetime` field in the statement table.  `new.*` can only refer to fields present in the table the trigger is present on.

Comment: I used 'new.Statement_Surname' it returned the same as value, I used  new.Statement_Surname without quotes it returned empty rows this is the actual problem.

Comment: You are missing the point. The actual problem is that in your trigger. `NEW.*` refers to fields from the table the trigger is against. In this case, it is  `pension_accounts`. There is NO statement_balance field in that table, so your trigger can't work. Also, it needs to be an after insert trigger. I'm going to update this answer.

Comment: Thank alot is small , I hope someday stackoverflow would add a buy me beer button so I could buy you a beer,  your updated answer worked like smoke...